# java polymorphism aliasing issue

Tags: java, polymorphism

If there's 3 classes. A, B and C. class B extends A and class C extends B.

class A has equals method:

```
public boolean equals(A other)
{...}
```

class B has equals method:

```
public boolean equals(B other)
{...}
```

and class C has euals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{...}
```

And the main has these code lines:

```
A a = new A();
C c = new C();
a=c;
System.out.println(a.equals(c));
```

I can't understand why the equals method of class A is being executed.

I know that overloaded methods are bonded using static binding. But a points to the "C part of the object" after aliasing and there's the method equals of class C. Why isn't it the equals method of class C that will execute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method in a subclass *overrides* a method in the superclass only if the parameters have the same types.

The `Object` class defines an `equals()` method:

```
class Object {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}
}
```

When you define class `A`, it inherits the `equals` routine from `Object`.  You define a new `equals`, but the parameter type is different, so it doesn't override the one in `Object`; instead, it becomes an overload.  The result is that `A` has two overloaded `equals` methods:

```
class A {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}  // inherited
    public boolean equals(A other) {...}     // the one you wrote
}
```

Similarly, the `equals` in `B` won't override either `equals`, so the result is three overloaded `equals` methods:

```
class B {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}  // inherited from Object
    public boolean equals(A other) {...}     // inherited from A
    public boolean equals(B other) {...}     // doesn't override anything
}
```

In class `C`, the new `equals` method *does* override the one in `Object`, so there are still three `equals` methods:

```
class C {
    public boolean equals(Object other) {...}  // overrides the one in Object
    public boolean equals(A other) {...}       // inherited from A
    public boolean equals(B other) {...}       // inherited from B
}
```

Now, here's your code:

```
A a = new A();
C c = new C();
a=c;
System.out.println(a.equals(c));
```

When you say `a.equals(c)`, the compiler sees that `a` has type `A`.  Therefore it looks at the methods in `A` to see which one to execute.  (The compiler doesn't know that `a` will have type `C` at run time; therefore, it won't look at the methods in `C`.)

There are two methods to choose from, as shown above:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}  // inherited
    public boolean equals(A other) {...}     // the one you wrote
```

Both of them could be used on the parameter `c`, since `c` is an `Object` and it is an `A`.  In that case, when one parameter is a subclass of the other, the compiler chooses the "closest" one, in essence.  `C` is only two subclasses away from `A`, and it's three subclasses away from `Object`, so it chooses the overload with parameter `A`, which is the one you defined in `A`.  And note that this `equals` method was never overridden.  So it executes the code that you wrote in class `A`.

But suppose you had written:

```
System.out.println(a.equals((Object)c));
```

By casting `c` to an `Object`, you're forcing the compiler to look at it as an `Object`.  Now when it chooses between the overloads, it must choose the one with the `Object` parameter, because an `Object` *cannot* automatically be converted to an `A` (because not every `Object` is an `A`).  Thus, it would choose the inherited method.  And since, at run time, the object actually is of class `C`, and since class `C` has an `equals` method that overrides the one in `Object`, in this case it *would* execute the code written in class `C`.

Your code is a nice example for demonstrating how overloading and overriding work.  In real life, however, it's a bad idea to write an `equals()` method whose parameter is anything other than `Object`, because it won't override and it could lead to confusion.  Also, it's a good practice to put `@Override` on any method that you think will override a method in a superclass.  That way, if you goof and use the wrong parameters, the compiler will catch it before you get a run-time bug that could be very difficult to track down.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, the line in main class `a=c;` ha no affect on which equals method will be executed. It is only `A a = new A();` that determines which equals method will be executed? So it also means that aliasing occurs in dynamic binding(run-time)?

Comment: Right; `a = c` has no effect on which `equals` method the compiler chooses between **overloaded** methods.  This is determined by the type of `a` (where you say `A a`) and the type of the parameter (which is of type `C` in your example).  If you make the parameter an `Object`, however, then `a = c` does affect which method gets run, between a method and its **overriding** methods.  (That's where polymorphism comes in.)  It's important to understand the difference between overloading and overriding.

Answer (score 4):

***Short answer***

Your method in child class gets *overridden* only when it have same method signature as that of parent class. Otherwise it doesn't.

---

Consider these two examples

**Example 1**

```
class A {
    public boolean equals(A Other) {
        System.out.println("A's method");
        return true;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public boolean equals(Object Other) {
        System.out.println("C's method");
        return true;
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.equals(null);
    }
}
```

**Output 1**

```
A's method
```

**Example 2**

```
class A {
    public boolean equals(A Other) {
        System.out.println("A's method");
        return true;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public boolean equals(A Other) {
        System.out.println("C's method");
        return true;
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.equals(null);
    }
}
```

**Output 2**

```
C's method
```

In example #1, you have changed the method signature when `equals()` method is defined in child class and so it doesn't qualify for *method overriding*. And so when calling this method from Driver class, parent's gets called.

*whereas* in example #2, the method signature in both parent and child are exactly the same and so *method overriding* takes place here and thus you get output that you were expecting in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Simple words, java handles aliasing during runtime. as overloaded method use static binding(compile time), it is calling A's equals method.
if you override equals method in class A.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){ ...}
```

it will be overridden method which uses dynamic binding(runtime) and C's equals method will be called.